# Get data value from UIPopOverPresentationController to UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipopover

i want to get the value from the presented popover. I googled around and got this answer

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    YourViewController *controller =  popoverController.contentViewController;
    MyData *data = controller.yourData;
    //Do something with data
}
```

But i have used UIPopOverPresentationController. So how am i going to get the value from these delegate method perhapsly

```
func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {

   // var controller = popoverPresentationController.


}
```

**OR Should i create delegate to pass data back to main View Controller ?**

Comment: thanks..that worked  ....can you write it as answer???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of `UIPopoverPresentationController`, it inherits from [`UIPresentationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPresentationController).

It has the properties `presentingViewController` and `presentedViewController`. One of which should reference the controller you want to access and pass data to/get data from:

```
func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    let controller = popoverPresentationController.presentedViewController
    // Fetch data from the presented controller
}
```